# What is the English word for a lawyer's client?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want an English word for an attorney (lawyer)'s client, i.e. someone who employs a lawyer to defend them in court. *Client* might actually be just fine, but I am looking for a word more consistent with its counterpart.

By counterpart I mean its opposing position e.g. employer -> employee, caller->callee, etc. The word might be used like this (using the non-existent counterpart lawyer -> lawyee to illustrate):

> She'd had a distinguished career as a lawyer, but now she was the
>   lawyee.

Comment: by _counterpart_ you mean _attorney/lawyer_? or counterpart in another language?

Comment: An attorney's client will be either plaintiff or defendant depending on whether he/she sues someone or is sued, respectively. This conveys the client's role in the process, though, not their relation to the attorney.

Comment: @MysticOdin By counterpart I mean its opposing position e.g. employer -> employee, caller->callee, etc.

Comment: You mean lawyer/lawyee? Interesting neologism!

Comment: I can't think of a counterpart like that unfortunately, but there is a term _employer-employee relationship_ and there is a term _attorney-client privilege_

Comment: *Client* is the term in the US.  In the case of a criminal charge the client might also be a *defendant*, and in the case of a civil court case the client might be either *defendant* or *plaintiff*.

Comment: @HotLicks **Or**, *respondent*.

Comment: If you really want to confuse people, use _attorney/attorner_. Or _attorneyer/attorneyee_.

Comment: But if you say, “... spent years as a public defender but now she was the defendant...” it could work.   (Although clearly not all lawyers are public defenders)

Comment: Thank you @Chappo for the edit. The question is now more clear.

Comment: Editing to improve questions/answers is one of the actions encouraged by this site. Rather than being just a Q&A forum, it becomes a valuable internet resource! PS feel free to wait if you think a better answer might be forthcoming, but don't forget to "tick" the answer you think provides the best solution to your question :-)

Answer (score 4):

Following the idea of counterparts, the appropriate pair is:

> **litigator / *litigant***

See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166899/single-word-for-plaintiff-or-defendant/166905?s=1%7C0.6625#166905) for initial reference. The following provides more detail, as I found that both terms are somewhat ambiguously defined in the standard online resources.

**Litigant** is defined by [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/litigant) as "A person involved in a lawsuit." [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/litigant?s=t) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litigant) offer a similar definition. Now, I'd always thought of a litigant as strictly the plaintiff, in the sense that they are the one who *litigates*, but it seems my reliance on the suffix [-ant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-ant) to denote the *agent* of the action (e.g. propel/propellant, defend/defendant) was misplaced.

To dispel any doubt, [this source](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/litigant) makes it clear that litigant means "plaintiff, defendant, petitioner, respondent, cross-complainant, and cross-defendant, *but not a witness or attorney*" [my emphasis].

**Litigator** has two meanings according to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/litigator) (but read on to see why this can't be trusted):

> 1. a courtroom lawyer.
> 2. a litigant.

It cites the word origin as

> agent noun from Latin *litigare* (see litigation ). Latin *litigator*
>   meant "a party to a lawsuit; litigant."

Unhelpfully, it also notes that "litigator" can be confused with "litigant".

Two other sources are even less useful: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/litigate?q=litigator#litigate__13) simply defines it as the noun derivative of "litigate", which means "Resort to legal action to settle a matter; be involved in a lawsuit", and similarly [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litigator) goes no further than naming it as the noun form, along with "litigation".

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/litigator) is equally unhelpful, defining *litigator* as "a person who litigates" but failing to specify whether the lawyer involved in the lawsuit is "litigating".

Thankfully, however, the same site has a "legal" tab. [*This* definition](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/litigator), citing *Burton's Legal Thesaurus*, is quite explicit:

> **litigator** *noun*
>   appointed counsel, attorney, counsel, counsel
>   representing a party, lead counnel, legal adversary, legal opponent,
>   litigating attorney, littgation counsel, of counsel, opposing counsel,
>   retained counsel

**TL;DR: On the basis of all the above, I think I can confidently declare that a *litigator* is a lawyer, and the counterpart - the *litigant* - is their client.**

Comment: Only some lawyers are litigators, and only some of their clients are litigants. Moreover, even in the situations in which the lawyer is a litigator and the lawyer's client a litigant, these words do not bring out that they are two parties to the same lawyer-client relationship; they are rather about their respective relationships to the rest of the legal system.

Comment: @jsw29 well of course; you may as well add that only some dogs are poodles, and only some poodles have fleas. But are all poodles *dogs*? Or, more relevantly, are all litigators *lawyers*? And can a flea also be a poodle? Or to cut to the chase: can a self-representing *litigant* in a lawsuit be correctly described as a *litigator* in that lawsuit?

Comment: Of course not (to the last two questions). In certain cases, the words *litigator* and *litigant* are perfectly apt. They will never be confused with each other. My point was merely that they are not related to each other in the way in which *employer* and *employee* are (which is what the OP sought), and that they cannot be used as the substitutes for *lawyer* and *client*, when one speaks of the lawyer-client relationship **in general** (which, again, seems to be what the OP sought). But then, there is no substitute for *client* in such contexts.

Comment: @jsw29 Your first comment does raise a valid question: does the lawyer-client relationship only exist in the context of litigation? Can a lawyer have a client who is not a litigant? I think the answer might be yes, but it may also come down to the [terminology in specific jurisdictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawyer#Terminology). And law is not my area of expertise: IANAL. ;-)

Comment: With all due respect, the answer to that question is emphatically yes, it's not just that it 'might be yes'. One becomes a lawyer's client when one asks a lawyer to incorporate one's business, to draft a contract, to get advice on the legal implications of a proposed business transaction, and so forth. In all these cases, as soon as one consults a lawyer, elaborate rules that govern lawyer-client relationships come into play. The terminological differences discussed in the linked Wikipedia entry do not affect that point.

Comment: @jsw29 emphatically NO for a barrister in England or Wales. The *only* thing a barrister may do in those jurisdictions is **represent their client in court, on the instructions of a solicitor**; this category of lawyer is specifically *disallowed* from "conducting litigation". Like I said, terminology and jurisdiction matter.

Comment: Of course, the clients of a barrister are, by definition, involved in litigation, and it has been obvious all along that you had something like barristers in mind in writing your answer. The question was, however, about the lawyer-client relationship **in general**, not about the barrister-client relationship specifically.

Answer (score 0):

At the trial level, the parties are typically called the plaintiff or petitioner and the defendant or respondent. On appeal, parties are called the appellant and appellee.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=define+appellant

Comment: None of these describe the lawyer/client relationship, only the role of the party in the court case.

Comment: Thanks@jsheeran, The question reads, to me, as "...i.e. someone who employs a lawyer to defend them in court." In this case would not the 'lawyer's' be the "possessive" (lawyer's), thus client of the lawyer?

Comment: I agree with @jsheeran: I think you've misunderstood the question's request for "counterpart" terms. The question makes it clear that one counterpart must be the lawyer, and the other counterpart must be their client. Appellant/appellee doesn't satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Hi @– Chappo Hasn't Forgotten Monica, Thanks for response. Taking another hard look at question.....